# What is the python equivalent of roipoly matlab function?

Tags: python, matlab

I'm working on a code to convert matlab functions into python. Here's the link for the [roipoly](https://in.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/roipoly.html) function which I'm working on. Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can this link help you?

> https://pypi.org/project/roipoly/

In its description :

> Small python module to select a polygonal region of interest (ROI) in
> an image that is stored as a numpy array. The usage is similar to the
> [[https://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/roipoly.html][roipoly]]
> function present in the image processing toolbox from MATLAB.